# How to dynamically show selected radio in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3

I have to show the radio will be selected if keyId will be match then show selected but its not working i am calling a function with selected and function is not call tell me anyone  how to call function with ion-select tell me anyone how to do this in ionic3?

```js
 checkedSelectedCategory(keyId) {
    //Used for show the checkbok will be true
    for(var i=0; i<this.adminCategoriesList.length;i++){
      if(this.adminCategoriesList[i].categoryKeyId == keyId) {
        return true;
      }
     }
  } `
```

```html
<ion-select interface="popover">
<ion-option *ngFor="let category of adminCategoriesList" [value]="category" selected="checkedSelectedCategory(category.categoryKeyId)">
          {{category.categoriesDto.categoryName}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind the selected value you are now just using the property selected without binding and thats why the function is not getting triggered.

```
<ion-select interface="popover">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let category of adminCategoriesList" [value]="category" [selected]="checkedSelectedCategory(category.categoryKeyId)">
      {{category.categoriesDto.categoryName}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```